# Is there any way to merge this two x-axis in one axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to combine the two x-axis in one axis.

I have two different series and the difference between them is in the time (some times in seconds and some times in minutes)

Here is my code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart:{
  renderTo:'chart',
  zoomType: 'xy',
  type:'line'
},
title: {
  text: '',
  x: -20
},
subtitle:{
  text:'',
  x: -20
},
xAxis:[{
  id:0,
  type:'categories',
  categories:finalarray.time1
},
{
  id:1,
  type:'categories',
  categories:finalarray.time2,
}],
yAxis:{
    title:{
      text:'',
      align:'high'
    },
    labels:{
      overflow:'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip:{
    crosshairs: [{
      width: 1,
      color: 'red'
    }, true],
    valueSuffix: ''
  },
  plotOptions:{
    series:{
      cursor:'pointer'
    },
    line:{
      dataLabels:{
        enabled:true
      }
    }
  },
  credits:{
    enabled:false
  },
  series:[
    {
      xAxis:0,
      name: finalarray.description1 + " ( " + finalarray.unit1 + " ) ",
      data: finalarray.value1
    },
    {
      xAxis:1,
      name: finalarray.description2 + " ( " + finalarray.unit2 + " ) ",
      data: finalarray.value2
    }
  ]
  });
```

[image: this is my chart !!]

Comment: This question is not properly asked. Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The fact that you didn't even bother to make the tiniest bit of effort to complete the 2-minute site tour also looks bad.

Comment: How do you want to merge the axes?

Answer (score 0):

To use only one `xAxis`, set the axis type to `datetime` and use data `x` values as timestamps:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            {x: 1547480600, y: 12},
            {x: 1547540600, y: 21},
            {x: 1547600600, y: 9},
            {x: 1547660600, y: 37}
        ]
    }, {
        data: [
            {x: 1547480600, y: 9},
            {x: 1547535600, y: 2},
            {x: 1547590600, y: 29},
            {x: 1547645600, y: 41}
        ]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9c2zba74/